# m/monit fails to send alerts on events

Tags: monit

I have a m/monit server running that used to send out alerts on events. Some time back, m/monit stopped sending alerts and in the `error.log` file for m/monit I see lines like:

> 2016-04-06 09:03:48 RuleManager: AssertException: address

Where the timestamps corresponds with known artificially created events. m/monit seems to pick up the events just fine, they are registered in m/monit and the "LED" symbols are updated accordingly.

The m/monit version is 2.3.3 (a bit old I know).

Hope someone has a good answer.

Regards

Jesper Rude Selknaes